# como hago para que los comentarios recien publicados vaya abajo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

tengo una caja de comentarios pero los comentarios recien publicados los pone de primeras, y quiero que vayan de último. de abajo hacia arriba "al réves" tipo mensajes de chat.

```
<main class="centered-bottom" id="main" role="main" tabindex="-1">
```

de ahí para abajo van puros `<article></article>`

¿como hago?

Comment: si es sql ORDER BY id_primario desc

Comment: difícil saber cómo sino muestras el código que pone los comentarios

Answer (score 1):

Solo con javascript podrías hacer algo así, en este ejemplo con cada mensaje se crea un nuevo `p` y se convierte en hijo del `div` comentarios, por lo que cada nuevo comentario se coloca debajo del anterior.

```js
var comentarios = document.getElementById("comentarios");
function enviar() {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  comentarios.appendChild(p);
  p.innerHTML = document.getElementById("input").value;
}
```

```css
.comentarios {width:200px;height:200px;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<input type="button" id="boton" value="Enviar" onclick="enviar()">
<div class="comentarios" id="comentarios"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo otra solución con `Jquery`:

```js
$('#boton').click(function(){
    $('#comentarios').append( $('#cajaTexto').val() + "<br>" );
    $('#cajaTexto').val('');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cajaTexto">
<input type="button" id="boton" value="Enviar"">
<div class="comentarios" id="comentarios"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```